# uploading images to firebase on form submit

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, angular-file-upload, ng-file-upload

I'm building a small web app (blog post alike) using AngularJs and Firebase.
i implemented the addPost controller earlier and it worked good. 
After i wanted to add some input file inside the form which already implemented to upload images to firebase on form submit using ng-file-upload directive . As a new in angular i knew that firebase can save images as base64 , so i found a function on the directive which can convert the images to base64 , but i got this error **ReferenceError: disallowObjectUrl is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.upload ** when i try to submit the form . 
i dont know what i'm doing wrong .
here is the project on github 
https://github.com/SaidThaher/HotelApp
The working files is addPost.html and addPost.js .
all the app files is in app folder.

Please help,, i spent 3 days in this.

**UPDATE**

Update : @danialfarid updated the directive and made my day :)

Upgrade to 8.0.6 and move your fb push here:

```
Upload.base64DataUrl(files).then(function(base64Urls) {
  fb.push({...
            images : base64Urls,
        },...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

variable disallowObjectUrl  is not defined at this line: https://github.com/SaidThaher/HotelApp/blob/master/app/js/addPost.js#L16

You should replace it with a boolean value which is `true` in your case.

```
Upload.dataUrl(files, true).then...
```

Comment: thank you, is the upload function must be in the addPost function or its right how i wrote the code.  please have a look and if its possible give some code to figur it out. thanx